# Getting No Module named error while executing python script using jenkins (shell commands)

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I have a GitHub - python project with 2 scripts. I can run one script in Jenkins using shell command - `python script_1_name.py` (this script doesn't have any external packages imported). I have another script which has a external packages - `jenkinsapi` and `jenkins`. when i try to run this script using shell command in jenkins - `python script_2_name.py`, I am getting the below error.

```
***22:29:36   File "createJenkinsJobs.py", line 1, in <module>
22:29:36     from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
22:29:36 ImportError: No module named jenkinsapi.jenkins
22:29:36 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
22:29:36 Finished: FAILURE***
```

Since i have these packages installed in virtual environment, i can successfully execute them in local. How to execute this using jenkins job.

Comment: These are the external libraries i am using in my script - from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
from jenkinsapi.utils.crumb_requester import CrumbRequester
import jenkins

Comment: try this ....https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/